# Web Component Referencing Knowledge Article Changed to Knowledge_Article__c

Tags: knowledge

I wrote lwc that is placed on the standard Knowledge Article layout.

The component reference field from the object:
**Knowledge_Article__kav.PublishStatus**

During the save from VS_code to the org it is working fine, however after the save when I'm retrieving the component the standard object is being changed to custom:
**Knowledge_Article__c.PublishStatus**

This causing error when I'm trying to deploy the component with external tool as **Knowledge_Article__c** is not a valid object.

Can reproduce by creating new lwc:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Knowledge_Article__kav.PublishStatus';

export default class TempArticleComponent extends LightningElement {}
```

save it to the org with vs Code, then retrieve it from the org with vs code.

Any idea? Is it SF bug?

Answer (score 1):

If you have lightning knowledge enabled the Standard Knowledge Article sObject API name is Knowledge__kav.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledge__kav.htm

Try

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Knowledge__kav.PublishStatus';

export default class TempArticleComponent extends LightningElement {}
```

Comment: There's a slightly different issue where Knowledge__kav is turned into Knowledge__c as discussed here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377719/strange-behaviour-knowledge-kav-gets-renamed-to-knowledge-c but your reported issue is "not a valid object"

Comment: This is strange. I'm no longer working with the customer that I faced this issue, but I'm 100% sure the object name I was using is Knowledge_Article__kav. Maybe it is different version of SF KA...