# Strange Behaviour: Knowledge__kav gets renamed to Knowledge__c

Tags: lightning-web-components, knowledge, vs-code

`import KNOWLEDGE_ARTICLE_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Knowledge__kav.Title';`

I have this simple piece of LWC code which when pushed to the org strangely resets Knowledge__kav to Knowledge__c EVERY SINGLE TIME.

`import KNOWLEDGE_ARTICLE_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Knowledge__c.Title';`

I came across a similar post from 12 months ago [Web Component Referencing Knowledge Article Changed to Knowledge_Article__c](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346165/web-component-referencing-knowledge-article-changed-to-knowledge-article-c) but it has no answers.

I am using VSCode to deploy/retrieve the component from the org.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior, it works fine in my sandbox, but when deploying to a target org i get "Invalid reference Knowledge__c.PublishStatus of type sobjectClass in file lwc_component.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `__kav` isn't supported to be imported in LWC. This is called out (though not explicitly) in [import limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about#:%7E:text=into%20map%20markers.-,Import%20Limitations,-Salesforce%20supports%20many) within [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

> Salesforce supports many object or field suffixes to represent different types of data. **Lightning Web Components** supports the import of references to standard objects, as well as the import of references to custom objects (__c) **only**

This comes across as confusing as you'd consider Knowledge objects to be under "standard objects". However, Knowledge is a bit different as covered in the [data model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_object_model.htm).

> The Knowledge object model is slightly different from other feature areas because it exposes a set of abstract Salesforce objects that aren’t directly used when you create articles. These abstract objects then contain concrete derivations that you do use when creating articles.

[image]

So while `__kav` wouldn't be supported by LWC imports - I presume the abstract version `KnowledgeArticleVersion` *might* work (haven't tested this myself). You'll also see it's the abstract version (`KnowledgeArticleVersion`) that is called out in the [Supported Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_all_supported_objects.htm) for the UI API as well. Otherwise, you may be left having to use apex to get information versus imports.